# Problem restoring a SQL Server 2008 DB running Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

Has anybody else had this issue?  I am running SQL Server 2008 Express and am attempting to restore a database from file.  When I click the 'Add' button to choose my backup file SQL Server stops responding.  I tried running in Vista SP2 compatibility mode, but that did not help.

Comment: Not programming, and should not be using beta products. Dont expect support.

Comment: True, I thought since it was at least related to programming that this would be a good place to try.

Comment: @leppie: RC is not beta. RC means if we don't find any horrible bugs, this is what's going to ship.

Comment: As I re-read that... why shouldn't I be using beta products?  Isn't that the point?

Answer (score 6):

You need SQL Server 2008 **SP1**

Comment: This could be the solution!

Comment: Yep, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your drive D: or C: or
   whatever has compression enabled if
   so uncheck and wait and repeat.
2. Check if backup is compatible for

   1. (check net for more on this).
3. Check if works on different
   environments...

Comment: I do not have compression enabled on the C drive.  At this point I just want to be able to select the backup file (I'm sure it is compatible with sql server 2008)... but I can't get that far.